# In CodeIgniter can't allow access to upload directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, directory

http://localhost/uploads/student_doc/15.doc

I can't access this directory. I used .htaccess to allow the access but that isn't working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Order deny,allow
Allow from all

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/uploads/student_doc
 Options +Indexes 
# or #
IndexIgnore *

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the uploads folder out side of application folder.

Comment: yes. It's in the root dir

Comment: What are the permissions for this folder?

Comment: I want to open the doc files of this DIR. just need to allow the whole upload DIR and it's files